# Spring NoSuchMethodError when calling ResponseEntity.getStatusCode

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, nosuchmethoderror

I have a spring boot application which is using spring boot web 3.0.3 and I have a lib that is using 2.6.7 spring boot web

but in my lib response.getStatusCode() is throwing an exception NoSuchMethodError but when I debbug with intellij I have the value

Any idea what maybe wrong ? my spring boot does not have many dependency : spring boot starter web (3.0.3), spring cloud startervault config (4.0.0), springdoc open ui (1.6.14), my lib (which i think is the problem) , commons-lang3, jackson-databind-nullable (0.2.6)

thanks in advance,
akaliza

Comment: If your application is using Spring Boot 3.0.3 then how come you lib is using Spring Boot web 2.6.7. This is conflict with BOM at the first place. Can you share some minimal reproducible example for the same

Comment: hi @akaliza, have you found any solution to this problem?